# GEOSparql : Make geospaql queries to multiple Datasets. Should I use triplestore? What architecture do you suggest?

Tags: rdf, geospatial, sparql, dbpedia

I want to use GEOsparql in order to resolve location based queries such as *[nearest university]*. I am thinking of using multiple data sources, such  as DBpedia LinkedGeodata Geonames etc. Should I download all these HUGE datasets and use a triplestore such as parliament? Or I can make my search on the cloud using particular sparql endpoints.
Would you suggest geosparql?
Also, I would like to ask if you would suggest a specific architecture for this sort of query resolvement.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading all datasets is certainly not necessary (I think it would be a monumental task anyway, if not impossible) - you can query several sparql endpoints from one sparql query. The sparql engine you are using has to support the SERVICE clause (SPARQL 1.1 conformity), as for example in [Join semantic endpoints in SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841770/join-semantic-endpoints-in-sparql-query) (scroll down a bit for the interesting bits).

The question on using geosparql is twofold:

- yes the vocabulary is useful if you are authoring your own dataset. At the moment, I believe it is the best way to describe geometries, particularly if your geometries comprise more than just points (in which case you could suffice using http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/)
- the current implementations of the geosparql functionality do not seem very robust or scalable, but for testing purposes, you could use a triple store with geosparql support as is currently available. This is certainly something you can use for the case of, for example, the nearest university as seen from a certain location. Be sure to check this study by GeoKnow to see what kind of support is given: http://svn.aksw.org/projects/GeoKnow/Public/D2.1.1_Market_and_Research_Overview.pdf, I found the document to be very helpful, althoug it is of course a snapshot of the state in roughly the first half of 2013 judging by the release date.

Good luck!